# How to insert values from editor to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP development. I am trying to insert values in database
  Using HTML form I had used PHP editor in form but I do not know how to insert
  values from editor to database.
  Here is the field there is no name attribute so how to insert value in
  database without the name attribute.

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="pwd">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Question:
        </label>
        <?php   
         echo $rte->GetString();
         ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't. Input fields without a `name` attribute will not be submitted.

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: RichTextEditor usin php i have to insert data from this editor so how to store data of this editor into variable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL for your database solution:

You will need an input field for this to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="post" action="yourphpfile.php">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Question:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="question" name="question">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$question = $_POST['question'];

$query = "INSERT INTO database (question) VALUES ($question);";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    //success
}
```

This is simply how I do my form actions. Some users like to use the `isset()` function on the same page, but I think making separate pages for actions is a bit more of an organized approach.